Can I post a question about my own answer to another question that has been criticized?
My situation is a bit peculiar and unusual: I posted an answer to a question around a month ago, and originally got 5 upvotes and accepted. Later OP unaccepted my answer, and recently a person told me through comments that my code is bad. Personally, I think my code has no problems at all, but I may be biased. I would like to know if my code needs improvement. Can I post it for review? Or should the code in my own answers not be reposted as a question to seek improvement? Thanks for any insights.

Referenced comments:

Your class is confusing. It has a field named num but also has a num parameter passed into each method. Every method behaves as a static method.
– Nayuki's
comment @2024-10-01 01:32:14Z
© CC BY-SA 4.0


@Nayuki You're mistaken. The methods are not static. They are normal methods. Also it's common practice to name numbers num, and although it is indeed a bit sloppy in letting the attribute and the parameters all have the same name, any reasonably experienced programmer (and I assume OP is) would be able to read the code without any problems. It is not confusing. ...
– Luke L's
comment @2024-10-01 04:04:46Z
© CC BY-SA 4.0


Also you seem to not understand the idea of encapsulation. The attribute self.num is not supposed to be used by any code outside of the class. Thus any other chances of confusion are eliminated. Also parameter names are somewhat an internal part too, unless of course you like to use keyword arguments. But if not, the parameter names are also hidden from code outside of the class. So, essentially both nums are not to be seen by outside code. I don't see why my code is confusing. Please reconsider your downvote.
– Luke L's
comment @2024-10-01 04:07:00Z
© CC BY-SA 4.0


It's hard to explain the deficiencies of your code in a comment. Put your code up for review if you want an explanation.
– Nayuki's
comment @2024-10-01 23:24:32Z
© CC BY-SA 4.0


@Nayuki Seriously, you're a bit biased. My code does not contain many deficiencies.
– Luke L's
comment @2024-10-02 01:15:49Z
© CC BY-SA 4.0


The code from this answer was used for a question on softwareengineering.stackexchange.
– Doc Brown's
comment @2024-10-02 05:32:54Z
© CC BY-SA 4.0


Yes. You can post your answer for review.

A bit of a side note. I recall I was going to answer the integer to word question, but got bored of writing the same answer again. A couple hours later Reinderien posted the exact answer I was writing up. If I hadn't seen the Q&A and just stumbled on your preposed question I'd have just started writing the same answer again. I'd recommend you directly acknowledge you know of a better solution (Reinderien's) and would like more structural feedback. As the comments are correct, and show a weakness in the structure of your answer.

"recently a person told me through comments that my code is bad" - I would not interpret it that way. Your code is not bad, but far from being perfect. I would interpret the comment as someone saying the code could be improved further.

Yes, if you have suggested code in an answer, it's often worthwhile having it reviewed too.  I've done that myself a few times.
Note that when posting the question it should be self-contained (include the problem statement and full code, rather than a fragment that might suffice in an answer).
